# Adding 2nd level Dropdown Navbar to 1 level

Tags: html, drop-down-menu, navbar

```html
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">What is it?</a></li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Inventory</a>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">X-box 360</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Building Blocks</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Decorations</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Redstone & Transportation</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Materials</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Food</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Tools, Weapons & Armor</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Brewing</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Miscellaneous</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">PC</a></li>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Building Blocks</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Decoration Blocks</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Redstone</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Transportation</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Miscellaneous</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Foodstuff</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Tools</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Combat</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Brewing</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Materials</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Mobile</a></li>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Materials</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Tools & Weapons</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Decoration Blocks</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Building Blocks</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">PS4</a></li>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Building Blocks</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Decorations</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Redstone & Transportation</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Materials</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Food</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Tools, Weapons & Armor</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Brewing</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Miscellaneous</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</nav>
```

That's my code so far; it does a single level drop down but I tried to add a second level by doing the same thing I did to get the first drop down and it wont work. Its for a school project and I have researched how to add a second level but nothing I've tried has helped so far, so if you guys could give me any advice, or show me where I need to add thing to make it work I would love it. Thanks!

Comment: You should add your css code to.

Comment: You tried the same thing? Please post that too :)

Comment: I don't have any CSS code.

Comment: 1. Add what you have in a fiddler and 2, if it possible add a image of your goal

Comment: You do! See that "</style>" at the top of your code? What's before it? Also, please add a JSfiddle

Comment: There are several problems with your markup, first please edit your markup and check start and close tags for all ul and li elements.

Comment: how do i add a jsfiddle? Sorry I'm new to this and the padding,width and color is above that.

Comment: Check if this is the desired result of your markup https://fiddle.jshell.net/zg48z3ou/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net (add code here, then add link to it in your question), ALSO add your padding width and color. We need that to help you.

Comment: When you are making a sub menu you dont have to close the   `li`, <li><a href= "#">PC</a></li>` because this is already close after the inner `</ul>

Comment: Not really. Im trying to make the  X-box,PS4, PC and Mobile tabs the first level and everything thats inside of those tabs the second level if that makes sense

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/907qknku/ Thats all the code I have. The building blocks and other subtitles are supposed to be the 2nd level

Answer (score 0):

First you need fix your html code, there are several error in markup, can you check if this is the desired menu, notice in your code example that you are closing li element before open ul for each submenu, this is an error, ul need to be inside li and after ul you should close parent li.

```css
a {
 color: #FFF;
}


nav {
 margin: 50px 0;
 background-color: #E64A19;
}

nav ul {
 padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
 list-style: none;
 position: relative;
 }
 
nav ul li {
 display:inline-block;
 background-color: #E64A19;
 }

nav a {
 display:block;
 padding:0 10px; 
 color:#FFF;
 font-size:20px;
 line-height: 60px;
 text-decoration:none;
}

nav a:hover { 
 background-color: #000000; 
}

/* Hide Dropdowns by Default */
nav ul ul {
 display: none;
 position: absolute; 
 top: 60px; /* the height of the main nav */
}
 
/* Display Dropdowns on Hover */
nav ul li:hover > ul {
 display:inherit;
}
 
/* Fisrt Tier Dropdown */
nav ul ul li {
 width:170px;
 float:none;
 display:list-item;
 position: relative;
}

/* Second, Third and more Tiers */
nav ul ul ul li {
 position: relative;
 top:-60px; 
 left:170px;
}

 
/* Change this in order to change the Dropdown symbol */
li > a:after { content:  ' +'; }
li > a:only-child:after { content: ''; }
```

```html
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">What is it?</a></li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Inventory</a>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">X-box 360</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Building Blocks</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Decorations</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Redstone &amp; Transportation</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Materials</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Food</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Tools, Weapons &amp; Armor</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Brewing</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Miscellaneous</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">PC</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Building Blocks</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Decoration Blocks</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Redstone</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Transportation</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Miscellaneous</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Foodstuff</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Tools</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Combat</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Brewing</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Materials</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Mobile</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Materials</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Tools &amp;amp; Weapons</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Decoration Blocks</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Building Blocks</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">PS4</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Building Blocks</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Decorations</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Redstone &amp; Transportation</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Materials</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Food</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Tools, Weapons &amp; Armor</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Brewing</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Miscellaneous</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

If you don't need two first items then you need extract from the first ul to individual ul.

You will need a portion of css code to format this menu.
can you view and example here https://codepen.io/andornagy/pen/xhiJH